# Opening a new GUI from existing one in PYQT freezes the GUI

Tags: python, pyqt

The Primary Idea is to call progress bar (child GUI) on a button click from main GUI. After clicking a "create" button on main GUI, following 3 problem occurs:

1. Sometimes it fails to execute
2. Sometimes "Cancel" button does not appear on child GUI
3. If both of above goes well then, I am not able to click cancel button.

I have following code which fails to execute. Below code is actual code  that someone can copy-paste and execute

```
import sys
try:
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
except:
    pass

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s


class Ui_dialog_progress(object):
    def setupUi(self, dialog_progress):
        dialog_progress.setObjectName("dialog_progress")
        dialog_progress.resize(401, 165)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(dialog_progress)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.lblFileName = QtGui.QLabel(dialog_progress)
        self.lblFileName.setText("")
        self.lblFileName.setObjectName("lblFileName")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lblFileName, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.pbarFileSize = QtGui.QProgressBar(dialog_progress)
        self.pbarFileSize.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.pbarFileSize.setObjectName("pbarFileSize")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pbarFileSize, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(dialog_progress)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pbarTotal = QtGui.QProgressBar(dialog_progress)
        self.pbarTotal.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.pbarTotal.setObjectName("pbarTotal")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pbarTotal, 3, 0, 1, 2)
        self.lblTotal = QtGui.QLabel(dialog_progress)
        self.lblTotal.setText("")
        self.lblTotal.setObjectName("lblTotal")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lblTotal, 4, 0, 1, 2)
        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(213, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 5, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.btnPbarCancel = QtGui.QPushButton(dialog_progress)
        self.btnPbarCancel.setObjectName("btnPbarCancel")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btnPbarCancel, 6, 1, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(dialog_progress)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(dialog_progress)

    def retranslateUi(self, dialog_progress):
        dialog_progress.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog_progress", "Dialog", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog_progress", "Total:", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.btnPbarCancel.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog_progress", "Cancel", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

class ProgressDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent = None)
        self.ui = Ui_dialog_progress()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
        signal = QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()")
        self.ui.btnPbarCancel.connect(self.ui.btnPbarCancel, signal, self.abort)

    def abort(self):
        print "abc"
        pass

class Ui_dialog_file(object):
    def setupUi(self, dialog_file):
        dialog_file.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dialog_file"))
        dialog_file.resize(101, 59)
        self.btnCreate = QtGui.QPushButton(dialog_file)
        self.btnCreate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 77, 25))
        self.btnCreate.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("btnCreate"))
        self.retranslateUi(dialog_file)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(dialog_file)

    def retranslateUi(self, dialog_file):
        dialog_file.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog_file", "file", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.btnCreate.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog_file", "Create", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

class Methods():
    def __init__(self, summaryFile = None):
        pass

    def pbar(self):
        i = 0 
        self.pd.ui.pbarTotal.setValue(0)
        self.pd.ui.pbarFileSize.setValue(0)
        j = 0
        while i < 100:
            while j < 100:
                self.pd.ui.pbarFileSize.setValue(j)
                j += 1
            i += 1
            j = 0
            self.pd.ui.pbarTotal.setValue(i)

class Worker(QtCore.QThread, Methods):
    def __init__(self, pd = None
             ):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.pd = pd

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()
        self.exiting = True

    def done(self):
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("workerDone()"))

    def run(self):
        self.pd.show()
        self.pbar()
        self.pd.hide()
        self.pd.destroy()

class App(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_dialog_file()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        signal = QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()")
        self.connect(self.ui.btnCreate, signal, self.create)

        self.pd = None

    def create(self):
        self.pd = ProgressDialog()

        self.worker = Worker(self.pd)

        self.worker.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":        
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = App()
    test.show()
    app.exec_()
```

***New code***

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import time
import random

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s


class Ui_dialog_progress(object):
    def setupUi(self, dialog_progress):
        dialog_progress.setObjectName("dialog_progress")
        dialog_progress.resize(401, 165)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(dialog_progress)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.lblFileName = QtGui.QLabel(dialog_progress)
        self.lblFileName.setText("")
        self.lblFileName.setObjectName("lblFileName")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lblFileName, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.pbarFileSize = QtGui.QProgressBar(dialog_progress)
        self.pbarFileSize.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.pbarFileSize.setObjectName("pbarFileSize")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pbarFileSize, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(dialog_progress)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pbarTotal = QtGui.QProgressBar(dialog_progress)
        self.pbarTotal.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.pbarTotal.setObjectName("pbarTotal")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pbarTotal, 3, 0, 1, 2)
        self.lblTotal = QtGui.QLabel(dialog_progress)
        self.lblTotal.setText("")
        self.lblTotal.setObjectName("lblTotal")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lblTotal, 4, 0, 1, 2)
        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(213, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 5, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.btnPbarCancel = QtGui.QPushButton(dialog_progress)
        self.btnPbarCancel.setObjectName("btnPbarCancel")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btnPbarCancel, 6, 1, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(dialog_progress)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(dialog_progress)

    def retranslateUi(self, dialog_progress):
        dialog_progress.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog_progress", "Dialog", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog_progress", "Total:", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.btnPbarCancel.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog_progress", "Cancel", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

class ProgressDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent = None)
        self.ui = Ui_dialog_progress()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)

class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    trigger = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    trcancel = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(random.random()*5)  # random sleep to imitate working
        self.trigger.emit()
        self.trcancel.emit()

class Ui_dialog_file(object):
    def setupUi(self, dialog_file):
        dialog_file.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dialog_file"))
        dialog_file.resize(101, 59)
        self.btnCreate = QtGui.QPushButton(dialog_file)
        self.btnCreate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 77, 25))
        self.btnCreate.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("btnCreate"))
        self.retranslateUi(dialog_file)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(dialog_file)

    def retranslateUi(self, dialog_file):
        dialog_file.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog_file", "file", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.btnCreate.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog_file", "Create", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

class Main(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_dialog_file()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.btnCreate.clicked.connect(self.start_threads)
        self.pd = ProgressDialog()
        self.pd.ui.btnPbarCancel.clicked.connect(self.stopp)

    def start_threads(self):
        thread = MyThread(self)    # create a thread
        thread.trigger.connect(self.pdialog)  # connect to it's signal
        thread.start()

    def pdialog(self):
        self.pd.show()
        i = 0 
        self.pd.ui.pbarTotal.setValue(0)
        self.pd.ui.pbarFileSize.setValue(0)
        j = 1
        while i < 100:
            while j <= 100:
                time.sleep(0.001)
                self.pd.ui.pbarFileSize.setValue(j)
                j += 1
            i += 1
            j = 1
            self.pd.ui.pbarTotal.setValue(i)

    def stopp(self):
        print "cancel pressed"
        self.pd.hide()
        self.pd.destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = Main()
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You should not access/modify GUI components from a different thread. That is a big _NO_ in Qt.

Comment: Gianluca, Can you help me in rearranging the code so that it won't fail?

Comment: You should use signals to communicate between GUI thread and main thread. You can find various examples here on SO. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694971/pyqt-update-gui) is one of my answers to start you off.

Comment: Avaris, Thanks for the solution. 've used your code in combination. It helped me in resolving the child GUI crashing issue. But I am facing below problems: 1> child GUI (progress bar GUI) does not recognise click events untill both the progress bars reaches to 100%, 2> As GUI does not recognise click events, cancel button could not be clicked 3> Child GUI could not be moved around the desktop. I have the new code under new code snippet

Comment: can somebody help me out please?