# qprogressbar bar stops updating if new qprogressbar is opened in case of multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I want to update the progress on progress-bar on some event. there are multiple events/threads and so the progress-bars associated with each of them. But when new thread is started previous thread stops updating the progress bar. This should not happen. Following could can be used:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s


class Ui_dialog_progress(object):
    def setupUi(self, dialog_progress):
        dialog_progress.setObjectName("dialog_progress")
        dialog_progress.resize(401, 165)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(dialog_progress)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.lblFileName = QtGui.QLabel(dialog_progress)
        self.lblFileName.setText("")
        self.lblFileName.setObjectName("lblFileName")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lblFileName, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.pbarFileSize = QtGui.QProgressBar(dialog_progress)
        self.pbarFileSize.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.pbarFileSize.setObjectName("pbarFileSize")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pbarFileSize, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(dialog_progress)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pbarTotal = QtGui.QProgressBar(dialog_progress)
        self.pbarTotal.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.pbarTotal.setObjectName("pbarTotal")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pbarTotal, 3, 0, 1, 2)
        self.lblTotal = QtGui.QLabel(dialog_progress)
        self.lblTotal.setText("")
        self.lblTotal.setObjectName("lblTotal")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lblTotal, 4, 0, 1, 2)
        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(213, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 5, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.btnPbarCancel = QtGui.QPushButton(dialog_progress)
        self.btnPbarCancel.setObjectName("btnPbarCancel")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btnPbarCancel, 6, 1, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(dialog_progress)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(dialog_progress)

    def retranslateUi(self, dialog_progress):
        dialog_progress.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog_progress", "Dialog", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog_progress", "Total:", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.btnPbarCancel.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog_progress", "Cancel", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

class Ui_dialog_file(object):
    def setupUi(self, dialog_file):
        dialog_file.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dialog_file"))
        dialog_file.resize(101, 59)
        self.btnCreate = QtGui.QPushButton(dialog_file)
        self.btnCreate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 77, 25))
        self.btnCreate.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("btnCreate"))
        self.retranslateUi(dialog_file)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(dialog_file)

    def retranslateUi(self, dialog_file):
        dialog_file.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog_file", "file", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.btnCreate.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog_file", "Create", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

class ProgressDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent = None)
        self.ui = Ui_dialog_progress()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
#        self.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)

class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    trigger = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    updateFPD = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    updateTPD = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.pd = ProgressDialog()
        signal = QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()")
        self.pd.ui.btnPbarCancel.connect(self.pd.ui.btnPbarCancel, signal, self.abort)
        self.aborted= False

    def run(self):
        self.trigger.emit()

    def abort(self):
        self.aborted = True
        print "aborted"
        self.pd.close()

    def setup(self, no):
        self.threadNo = no
        self.name = "Thread %d"%self.threadNo

class Main(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_dialog_file()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.btnCreate.clicked.connect(self.start_threads)
        self.count = 0
        self.threadPool = []

    def start_threads(self):
        self.mythread = MyThread(self)
        self.mythread.setup(self.count)
        self.count += 1
        self.mythread.trigger.connect(self.pdialog)
        self.mythread.start()
        self.threadPool.append(self.count)

    def abort(self):
        self.mythread.stop()

    def pdialog(self):
        self.mythread.pd.show()
        i = 1
        self.mythread.pd.ui.pbarTotal.setValue(0)
        self.mythread.pd.ui.pbarFileSize.setValue(0)
        self.mythread.pd.setWindowTitle(self.mythread.name)
        j = 1
        while i < 100:
            while j <= 100:
                self.mythread.pd.ui.lblFileName.setText(self.mythread.name)
                self.mythread.pd.ui.pbarFileSize.setValue(j)
                print "name: %s, fileprogress: %d"%(self.mythread.name,j)
                QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
                j += 1
            i += 1
            j = 1
            self.mythread.pd.ui.pbarTotal.setValue(i)
            print "name: %s, total progress %d"%(self.mythread.name, i)
            QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
            if self.mythread.aborted:
                return
        self.mythread.pd.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = Main()
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

please find my new code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import time


try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s


class Ui_dialog_progress(object):
    def setupUi(self, dialog_progress):
        dialog_progress.setObjectName("dialog_progress")
        dialog_progress.resize(401, 165)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(dialog_progress)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.lblFileName = QtGui.QLabel(dialog_progress)
        self.lblFileName.setText("")
        self.lblFileName.setObjectName("lblFileName")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lblFileName, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.pbarFileSize = QtGui.QProgressBar(dialog_progress)
        self.pbarFileSize.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.pbarFileSize.setObjectName("pbarFileSize")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pbarFileSize, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(dialog_progress)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.pbarTotal = QtGui.QProgressBar(dialog_progress)
        self.pbarTotal.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.pbarTotal.setObjectName("pbarTotal")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pbarTotal, 3, 0, 1, 2)
        self.lblTotal = QtGui.QLabel(dialog_progress)
        self.lblTotal.setText("")
        self.lblTotal.setObjectName("lblTotal")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lblTotal, 4, 0, 1, 2)
        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(213, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        spacerItem1 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 5, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.btnPbarCancel = QtGui.QPushButton(dialog_progress)
        self.btnPbarCancel.setObjectName("btnPbarCancel")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btnPbarCancel, 6, 1, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(dialog_progress)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(dialog_progress)

    def retranslateUi(self, dialog_progress):
        dialog_progress.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog_progress", "Dialog", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog_progress", "Total:", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.btnPbarCancel.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog_progress", "Cancel", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

class Ui_dialog_file(object):
    def setupUi(self, dialog_file):
        dialog_file.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dialog_file"))
        dialog_file.resize(101, 59)
        self.btnCreate = QtGui.QPushButton(dialog_file)
        self.btnCreate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 77, 25))
        self.btnCreate.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("btnCreate"))
        self.retranslateUi(dialog_file)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(dialog_file)

    def retranslateUi(self, dialog_file):
        dialog_file.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog_file", "file", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.btnCreate.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("dialog_file", "Create", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

class ProgressDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent=None)
        self.ui = Ui_dialog_progress()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
#        self.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)

class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    trigger = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    updateFPD = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, QtCore.QString)
    updateTPD = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, QtCore.QString)
    showpdSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool)

    def __init__(self, parent=None, no=0):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.aborted = False
        self.threadNo = no
#        self.name = "Thread %d"%self.threadNo

    def run(self):
        self.trigger.emit()

    def emitSignals(self, iprogress=-99, tprogress=-99, \
                updateFPDSignal=True, updateTPDSignal=None, \
                showpdSignal=False, peSignal=None, msg=None
                ):
        if updateFPDSignal:
            self.updateFPD.emit(iprogress, msg)
        if updateTPDSignal:
            self.updateTPD.emit(tprogress, msg)
        if showpdSignal:
            self.showpdSignal.emit(True)
        else:
            self.showpdSignal.emit(False)
        if peSignal:
            QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()

    def abort(self):
        self.aborted = True
        print "aborted"

    def stop(self):
        self.terminate()

class Main(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_dialog_file()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.btnCreate.clicked.connect(self.start_threads)
        self.count = 0
        self.threadPool = []

    def start_threads(self):
        self.mythread = MyThread()
        self.pd = ProgressDialog()
        self.pd.ui.btnPbarCancel.clicked.connect(self.abort)
        self.mythread.trigger.connect(self.pdialog)
        self.mythread.updateFPD.connect(self.updateFileProgress)
        self.mythread.updateTPD.connect(self.updateTotalProgress)
        self.mythread.start()
        self.threadPool.append(self.mythread)

    def abort(self):
        self.pd.close()
        self.mythread.aborted = True

    def updateFileProgress(self, j, name):
        self.pd.ui.lblFileName.setText(name)
        self.pd.ui.pbarFileSize.setValue(j)
#        print "name: %s, fileprogress: %d" % (name, j)

    def updateTotalProgress(self, i, name):
        self.pd.ui.pbarTotal.setValue(i)
#        print "name: %s, total progress %d" % (name, i)

    def showProgressDialog(self, show):
        if show:
            self.pd.show()
        else:
            self.pd.close()

    def pdialog(self):
        self.pd.show()
        i = 1
        self.threadPool[len(self.threadPool) - 1].emitSignals(iprogress=0 , tprogress=0, updateFPDSignal=True,
                                updateTPDSignal=True, showpdSignal=True, msg="")
        j = 1
        while i < 100:
            while j <= 100:
                self.threadPool[len(self.threadPool) - 1].emitSignals(iprogress=j, updateFPDSignal=True, \
                                        peSignal=True, msg="")
                j += 1
            i += 1
            j = 1
            self.threadPool[len(self.threadPool) - 1].emitSignals(tprogress=i, updateTPDSignal=True, \
                                          peSignal=True, msg="")
            if self.threadPool[len(self.threadPool) - 1].aborted:
                return
        self.threadPool[len(self.threadPool) - 1].sleep(2)
        self.pd.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = Main()
    mainwindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Widgets should only be controlled by the main ui thread(i.e the thread that is in control of the main event-loop). If a widget exists outside the main thread then it will most likely not receive any updates, nor will it post any events such as it being clicked. Don't have your threads owning and/or manipulating ui widgets. In this particular case you don't need `MyThread` at all.

Let me use an example.

```
import time
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):

    progress_changed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    def run(self):
        for x in range(101):
            #we do not interect with the progress bar directly
            self.progress_changed.emit(x)
            time.sleep(0.1)


class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.progress_thread1 = MyThread()
        self.progress_thread2 = MyThread()

        self.progress_bar1 = QtGui.QProgressBar()
        self.progress_bar1.setMinimum(0)
        self.progress_bar1.setMaximum(100)

        self.progress_bar2 = QtGui.QProgressBar()
        self.progress_bar2.setMinimum(0)
        self.progress_bar2.setMaximum(100)


        """
        the progress is emmited through the thread's progress_changed signal
        we connect that signal to our updateProgress method which will
        be used to set the progress_bar's value

        you can also just connect it directly to the progress bar's setValue method
        self.progress_thread.progress_changed.connect(self.progress_bar.setValue)
        """
        self.progress_thread1.progress_changed.connect(self.updateProgress1)

        self.progress_thread2.progress_changed.connect(self.updateProgress2)

        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.progress_bar1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.progress_bar2)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.progress_thread1.start()
        self.progress_thread2.start()


    def updateProgress1(self, progress):
        self.progress_bar1.setValue(progress)

    def updateProgress2(self, progress):
        self.progress_bar2.setValue(progress)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.show()
    r = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(r)
```

Copy this to an empty python script and run it.

Comment: Vikki, but if I wanted to do it using MyThread. So can you modify existing code so, that it will work?

Comment: No. It simply won't work. The ideal way to do it is to let the work be done in your thread then emit a signal when progress changes. The signal should then be consumed by any thing on the ui thread to update the progress bar. The way qt (and most other gui frameworks) works, it's just not feasible for threads to interact directly with widgets.

Comment: Vikki, I did it the same way. MyThread was doing the work. In that case GUI freezes or crashes. Look for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855361/opening-a-new-gui-from-existing-one-in-pyqt-freezes-the-gui

Comment: but `MyThread` has `ProgressDialog` as a member, you're essentially trying to interact with a gui element from your thread, which is wrong. create the `ProgressDialog` in the main thread.

Comment: Vikki, I did the same thing then. I stopped interacting GUI element from MyThread and created the ProgressDialog in the main thread. Now if I spawn multiple threads(ProgressDialog), then only latest ProgressDialog shows progress and others won't. Help in resolving this. I am a new bee to coding.

Comment: Vikki, could please provide me the multithreaded example where one thread talks to one progressbar

Comment: @vishalekhe what i've posted does just that.

Comment: vikki, how? I did not get it. Can you please create multiple threads?

Comment: @vishalekhe the code in `MyThread` class will run in its own separate thread. The code in `MyWidget` will (and should always) run in the main gui thread.

Comment: Vikki, I am not sure that whether you got me or not? I understood what you want to say. But I want this code for multiple MyThreads. In this one mythread starts and it updates its progress bar. I want 2 or more mythreads and they update their respective progress bars.

Comment: @vishalekhe its the same concept. Just create another thread, let it emit its own signal and then connect that signal to another progress bar. Notice that in my example I said you can connect the signal directly to the progress bar's `setValue` method, just make sure the signal emits a value that can be consumed by `setValue`, in this case a number between 0 and 100.

Comment: @vishalekhe please don't edit the answer that way. The code you posted is almost right, just create another progress bar and update it in the second updateProgress method.

Comment: Vikki, can you please give me the code? I am not able to crate the another progress bar and so.